# When is hook_user_presave triggered?

Tags: users

I'm trying to create a little module that operates on similar principals as a shopping cart, but has nothing to do with e-commerce. I want to add paired values to `$user->data['cart']` on a very frequent basis. Everyone seems to agree that hook_user_presave is the way to do this. My question is this, when does hook_user_presave trigger? Can it be called from inside another fucntion or an .inc file, or does it happen on pageload? I am absolutely befuddled, since I thought hooks were basically event handlers for Drupal Core.

Can I, say, do the following?

```
test.module:
<?php
function mymodule_user_presave (&$edit, $account, $category) {
    $edit['data']['cart'] = $edit;
}
/* ... */

test.inc:
<?php
/* ... */
function mysavefunction () {
  $myvar = array('sweetdata' => 5);
  $account = user_load($user -> uid);
  mymodule_user_presave ($myvar, $account) 
}
/* ... */
```

If you could even point me to some documentation other than [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) useless api page, I would be greatly in your debt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`hook_user_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) is an event listener that's called when a user account is saved.

It's invoked from [`user_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) and shouldn't normally be called manually.

```
// Invoke hook_user_presave() for all modules.
user_module_invoke('presave', $edit, $account, $category);
```

If you want to save data on the user account, just use `user_save`

Comment: Okay, got it. I was just terribly confused by the way the api is described. The manual makes it sound like it's the preferred way to interact with $user->data.

Comment: You could set `$account->data` in `hook_user_presave`, but the `$account` will need to be saved first with `user_save`. Hence, perhaps simpler to just set it and use `user_save($account);` (unless the account is already being saved by something else)